# Solve Newtons Cooling Method with ODE23 Matlab

Tags: matlab, ode, differential-equations

I'm new to Matlab and trying to solve the Newton cooling `DEQ` with `ODE23`, actually a [simplified](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4822-using-numerical-computing-with-matlab-in-the-classroom?focused=6778439&tab=function) version of it. I am not sure how to input the function into the ODE function.

I have `T_s = 19, T_c = 84`, and `r = 0.025` elapsing from `[0, 300] seconds`.

The equation is `(dT_c)/dt = -r(T_c - T_s)`

Can anyone help me use the linked function to solve this DEQ?

Answer (score 1):

Matlab supports  [higher order functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) as well as [anonymous functions](https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html).  You can pass `f(T_c, t)` to `ode23tx`
as follows:

```
ode23tx(@(T_c, T_s)(-r*(T_c - T_s), tspan, y0, arg4, varargin)
```

I have assumed `r` is constant but you can change this trivially.
Read the [documentation](https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4822-using-numerical-computing-with-matlab-in-the-classroom?focused=6778439&tab=function&requestedDomain=true) of the linked function for details of the other
parameters.